# ANgular jS radio button model update

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to bind object value to radio button.My controller is like below.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('TestController',function($scope){
$scope.persons = [{ name: 'JOHN', isActive: false }, { name: 'Peter',      isActive: true }, { name: 'Sam', isActive: false }];
})
```

When I first time click the option button model(isactive changes to true) after that if i again click model is not updating to false.

https://jsfiddle.net/nuL4heut/

Comment: Have a look here and compare your HTML to theirs : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Comment: Andrew,Thanks I am able to display the records as per document and the true and false shows correctly in radio button.if i select "john" my model gets updated to true.Next if i select peter my previous model is not updating to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the changes I've made in your code here 
https://jsfiddle.net/nuL4heut/25/

What I changed is :

. Usage of ng-check instead of `ng-model`, both works but `ng-check` is more readable and doesn't change in the object when your check the radio button

. A function called `updatePerson` that is triggered when clicking on the radio button, changing your chosen person active status to true and the one you've chosen before to false

Comment: Druid,Thanks Got it have to use function thought by giving ngmodel will work.Another note is ng-check doesn't select the radio button as selected if the value is true.so have to use ngmodel and value="true"

Comment: You're welcome, `ng-check` selection the radio button when the condition inside it is satisfied